# show edit form instead inline edition

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a formatter edit button to edit a row, I defined it in conModel

```
colModel:[ 
        {name:'HOSTID', index:'HOSTID', width:120, editable: true, editoptions:{size:"15", maxlength:"10"}}, 
        {name:'NAME', index:'NAME', width:250}, 
        {name:'DOCUMENT', index:'DOCUMENT', width:75, editable: true, editoptions:{size:"15", maxlength:"15"}},
        {name:'IDMUREX', index:'IDMUREX', width:80, editable: true, editoptions:{size:"15", maxlength:"4"}},
        {name:'TYPE', index:'TYPE', width:60, formatter: 'select',
            edittype: 'select', align: 'center', editable: true, 
            editoptions: {value: 'T:<bean:message bundle="mantenimiento" key="titularidad.titularalto"/>;C:<bean:message bundle="mantenimiento" key="titularidad.cotitularalto"/>', defaultValue: ''}},
        {name: 'ACTIONS', width:50, fixed:true, sortable:false, search:false, resize:false, formatter:'actions', 
            formatoptions:{
                keys:true,
                editOptions: {
                    modal: true,
                    width: 'auto',
                    closeAfterEdit: true,
                    closeOnEscape: true,
                    recreateForm: true
                },
```

When I click on edit button, I have inline edition on the row, but I need to show the edit form.

How I can do it?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`formatter: "actions"` supports `editformbutton: true` option which you can use. You need just include it  as additional property of `formatoptions`. You can remove `keys:true` in the case from `formatoptions` because the option will be used only in case of inline editing.